# Angular UI TinyMCE : How set default settings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui

I am using angular ui tinymce extension. I would like to know how to set the following setting which I can do in regular JavaScript.

```
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",        
    height: 250,
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",

    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
        { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
    ]
});
```

Not sure how to use the setup

```
 $scope.tinymceOptions  =
 {
   setup: function (ed) {
     ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
         //SOME INITIALIZING CODE HERE

    });
  }
```

Any help related to setting up tinymceOptions would be appreciated.

Comment: Put that in a directive. Checkout the Angularjs's directive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[tinymce directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/blob/master/src/tinymce.js)**

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('BDA', ['ui.tinymce']);

app.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.tinymceOptions = {
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        height: "200px",
        width: "650px"
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="PostCtrl">
     <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinymceModel"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you; I didn't know how to make the link button show up!